# Firestore: I have 1 doc.set() and 2 snapshotChanges() on collection

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

in Firestore: when I set a doc with a propriety timestamp: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp();

I have two snapshotChanges in the collection with my doc:

1- action: "added" myObject with ( timestamp: null )

2- action: "modified" myObject with ( timestamp: 12345566778 )

So, I have one doc.set() and two snapshotChanges, 
please, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first change comes from the fact that the client recognized its own added document. But it doesn't know the timestamp yet, because that's computed on the backend.

The second change comes from the update of the document on the server with the timestamp.

In general, you can expect the client to recognize its own changes locally *before* anything happens on the backend, and you can expect further updates *after* things happen on the backend.

Comment: thanks, I hope I understand, but i have a doubt, please:
if there is another client connected in realtime he reads two time the 'new entry', and the cost? ok maybe is irrilevant but if i want use 'many backend timestamp' the cost increases? grazie, I hope in my english to, ciao

Comment: Other clients won't see it this  way.  This is special to clients that observe their own changes before anything happens on the server.